# How do I stop water from covering the map in the conquer the world campaign?

Tags: rise-of-nations

I am not sure if this is a bug in the game, but I've reinstalled the game completely many times. Whenever I play a "conquer the world" campaign, after a certain amount of time the map becomes filled with the sea and water. Though the game is still working, I am not able to play because of the terrain. I've tried to google it, but I am not able to find anything about this.

How can I avoid or fix this issue?

Comment: Are you playing with just the base game?  Or with the expansion?  If the expansion, which Conquer the World scenario?

Comment: What types of battles does this happen with? All?

Comment: not the expansion just the regular game, not all, some of the battles this happens, no specific pattern, it just happends suddenly

Comment: This wouldn't be a copy protection issue, would it? You have a fully legitimate license?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot?

Comment: Could you provide some sort of update for this question, screenshots maybe if you found out the issue or anything that may help me answer your question?